# DJANGO many to one

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I need your help, is really basic.
I have two models, Autor and Post with a many to one relationship. I'm having problems retrieving the data in the html page. What I want to do is list all the posts for a specific Autor within a FOR and besides that I need to show the first name and last name of the autor out of the FOR.

I really appreciate your help.

````
class Autor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Last Name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'autor' 
        verbose_name = 'Autor' 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Autors' 
        ordering = ['id'] 

class Post(models.Model):
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, verbose_name='Post')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'post' 
        verbose_name = 'Post' 
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts' 
        ordering = ['id'] ```
````

Comment: You can also do `posts = Post.objects.filter(author=some_author)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify a related_name attribute in ForeignKey definition, Django automatically creates a related_name using the name of your model with the suffix _set, for example, if sample_author is an instance of Author, this query returns all posts of the sample_author:

```
author_posts = sample_author.post_set.all()
```

then you can use all posts that exist in the result of this query within a FOR loop.

```
for post in author_posts:
    do something
```

outside of this loop, you can access to first_name and last_name of the sample_author instance by `sample_author.first_name` and `sample_author.last_name`

.